# How to prevent cycling shorts damage from brooks swallow saddle?

Tags: road-bike, saddle

I am new to cycling and I have brooks swallow saddle and pair of cycling shorts. After the ride, I observed that the short's fabric is a bit damaged. This happened at the same place for both shorts. I don't know what exactly is causing this to happen. Can someone please suggest me on how to prevent this?

I also applied saddle cream after buying the saddle. This happened immediately after the first ride with both shorts.
please find image details here -

Castelli - [image: https://imgur.com/a/4ueuKHW]

Gambitt - [image: https://imgur.com/a/kUxU98M]

saddle image - [image: https://imgur.com/OWPsYJ6]

**EDIT**- short full photo - https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPEbc.jpg

**EDIT** - possible reason - https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dfzm.jpg

Comment: Check for sharp edges!

Comment: Exactly what saddle cream did you apply, and to what?   Brooks normally recommend Proofide for their leather saddles.  By contrast, chamois cream goes on the clothes, and various products go on your skin directly.

Comment: @Criggie, i used Velo orange saddle care. i applied it on the saddle and allowed it to dry for a day

Comment: Where is the center line of your shorts in your photographs?  If the heavy stitching is the edge of the chamois in your shorts, the worn areas on your shorts are probably 8-10 cm from the centerline and maybe not in contact with the saddle.  To me, they look like they might be caused by contact with the saddle clamp or, as noted in a earlier comment, a sharp edge on the saddle itself.   Are both sides of the shorts getting worn, or just one side?

Comment: @AndrewHenle I updated description with the full picture of short and a small crack I found under saddle. can you please tell me, if this can be the reason?

Comment: @Satyaaditya Please use the button in the edit dialog to upload pictures. It is a pain to include them from your links.

Comment: Can you add a picture of your saddle bag - specifically how it attaches under the saddle?
There seems to be some sort of tab sticking out there - that's most likely the source of your problem

Comment: @Andy P, the saddle picture in the description includes the saddle bag. The yellow colour one.

Comment: I'd be surprised if that small cut in the edge of the saddle leather is causing the problem - it looks to be too far under the bend at the bottom edge of the saddle to rub against your shorts.  But just drape the shorts over the saddle like you were wearing them and note where the worn spot is likely to hit.  There can't be too many options - whatever it lines up against is almost certainly the cause.  Next time you're riding, see if you can feel the inside of your leg at that point rubbing - maybe it only happens when you're standing, for example.

Comment: Yes, you are right. it is not causing the problem. I saw the point where it getting point of contact and since its, a leather saddle te added friction is causing damage it seems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the root cause after confirming the issue with the bicycle store. Also, I thank, @Andrew Henle for helping me out in finding the issue.

There are two reasons for my shorts being damaged with this brooks saddle.

1. My left leg is seaming inwards (arch is dropping inwards) while pedalling which is the reason, my left thigh is constantly touching the saddle front part.
2. My brooks saddle has a slight bulge towards the left side at front of the saddle, which has to be straight. And the friction due to this rubbing on leather is a catalyst in this damage.

The bicycle expert in-store suggested me to go for a non-leather saddle for now.